# Are these two notions of "computable function" the same or related?

Tags: logic, computer-science, computability

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicomputable_function, we have:

"If a partial function is both upper and lower semicomputable it is called computable."

Is this the same kind of "computable (partial) function" as defined here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function

If so, can you provide a proof?

If not, is there some straightforward way they are related?

Comment: It is clear that the first definition is weaker than the second, since a computable (or any) function is bounded above and below by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The semicomputable functions being described are functions from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. These are an entirely different kind of function than the functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.  So the two notions of "computability" are not the same, because they are about different kinds of objects.

They are related, of course, in that they both use Turing machines somehow. But it is very different to use a Turing machine to compute a natural number than it is to use a Turing machine to compute a real number.

Comment: What do you mean "and entirely different kind of function"?  Just that the domain and range are different, as you stated?  

Are you suggesting there is no unified definition of "computable function" that would describe both cases?